How do I address internal led in Arduino framework raspberry pi pico W?
I am trying to use the internal led of a Rapsberry pi pico w
The exact point of the question is the "w" version of the raspberry pi; internal led is not pin 25 but I was unable to figure it out.
I tried several addresses up to 32767 with no result:
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void try_led(uint led_n)
{
  pinMode(led_n, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led_n, 1);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(led_n, 0);
  delay(200);
}

void loop()
{
  for (uint led = 0; led < 32767; led++)
  {
    Serial.println(led);
    try_led(led);
  }
}

Is internal led supported?
How can I address it?

did you try to use the macro LED_BUILTIN as shown in the Blink example?

Yes, but the macro addresses pin 25 that works for the normal "non w" version of the pico...

did you select Pico W in the Tools menu?

don't turn off the LED in your code ... that way it is easy to see when it turns on

Are you using Arduino Pico framework by Earle PHilhower? I saw a recent fix on v4.3.1 that suppose fixed the LED problem. Do a library update to make sure you had the v4.3.1 if you are using the Arduino-Pico core.

FYI. For Pico W, the LED is WL_GPIO0 on the Infineon 43439 WiFi chip.

I am using Arduino IDE via Platformio and I was not able to find distinction for the "w"...
Where is WL_GPIO0 defined?

As far as I know, the Pico W's internal LED is connected to the Wi-Fi chip (CYW43439) and controlled via GPIO 2.

I am using Arduino IDE via Platformio okay so what's the platformio.ini? If you selected your board = rpipicow, then LED_BUILTIN will be correct.
